# Trying to print two functions starting on the same line

Tags: python, image, loops

I'm trying to print the top half  of a diamond with two helper functions, and a main. this is my code:

```
def top_right(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size // 2 + 1
    spaces = nsize - 1

    for num in range(1, nsize + 1):
        line += str(num)
        print(spaces * ' ' + line)

def top_left(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size // 2 + 1

    print()
    for num in range(2, nsize + 1):
        spaces = nsize - num
        line += str(num)
        print(spaces * ' ' + line[::-1])

def full_diamond(size):
    top_left(size), top_right(size)
```

the full diamond function comes out with this:

```
full_diamond(17)

       2
      32
     432
    5432
   65432
  765432
 8765432
98765432
        1
        12
        123
        1234
        12345
        123456
        1234567
        12345678
        123456789
```

how do i get these two triangles to print o the same line, like the top half of a diamond?

Comment: Combine the two loops into a single loop.  Compute the left and right strings.  Then print them both out together.  Simple.

Comment: I just want to add to what @TomKarzes said. Keep in mind that your loops are actually indexed differently. So you'll need to start your loop at 1 and make sure your first line only prints it once.

Comment: They have two different ranges, so when I combine them, how do i keep those differences? sorry, i'm very new to programming haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncio:

```
import asyncio

async def top_right(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size//2+1
    spaces = nsize-1
    for num in range(1, nsize+1, 1):
        line+=str(num)
        print(spaces* ' '+line)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

async def top_left(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size//2+1
    print()
    for num in range(2, nsize+1, 1):
        spaces = nsize - num
        line+=str(num)

        print(spaces*' '+line[::-1], end='')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

def full_diamond(size):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [top_left(size), top_right(size)]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

This code works only with Python 3.5 or greater

Comment: You can, but why would you need to?

Comment: Thank you so much, you guys are so helpful and quick to do so as well!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more complicated answer than you are looking for - but you can make a very simple modification to your code to make it work with python generators.

The way you'd do this is to turn each function into a generator that returns the string you want to print (instead of directly calling print).  Then, you change `full_diamond` to iterate over the generators.  One final change is you have to move the extra spaces you were printing in `top_right`.

Here's the final code:

```
def top_right(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size//2+1
    spaces = nsize-1

    for num in range(1, nsize+1, 1):
        line+=str(num)
        yield(line)

def top_left(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size//2+1

    for num in range(2, nsize+1, 1):
        spaces = nsize - num
        line+=str(num)
        yield(spaces*' '+line[::-1])

def full_diamond(size):
    for i, j in zip(top_left(size), top_right(size)):
        print(i + j)

full_diamond(16)
```

And the output:

```
       21
      3212
     432123
    54321234
   6543212345
  765432123456
 87654321234567
9876543212345678
```

Again, you may find it simpler to just join the two loops together in one function.  However, I find the above to be a very pythonic solution, so it may work for you.

Comment: thank you so much, you guys are so helpful and quick at it as well!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but here's an example of how it could be done. I assume the first 1 has to be at the v top, right?

```
def top_right(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size // 2 + 1
    spaces = nsize - 1

    output = list()
    for num in range(1, nsize + 1):
        line += str(num)
        output.append(line + '\n')

    return output

def top_left(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size // 2 + 1

    output = [(nsize - 1) * ' ']
    for num in range(2, nsize + 1):
        spaces = nsize - num
        line += str(num)
        output.append(spaces * ' ' + line[::-1])

    return output


def full_diamond(size):
    for i, j in zip (top_left(size), top_right(size)):
        print (i+j)
```

Output for `full_diamond(17)`:

```
        1
       212
      32123
     4321234
    543212345
   65432123456
  7654321234567
 876543212345678
98765432123456789
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am trying to do! I was not sure if making it all into one print statement was the simplest way or not.

Comment: Glad to be of help. There is a lot more in your code that could be done to make it cleaner, more effective, less repetitive and more pythonic. I'd encourage you to keep experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding it difficult to structure your solution because you have decomposed it in a way that does not match the structure of your required output very well.

I am presuming, due to the structure of your output, that you would never call `full_diamond` with an even argument, and wondering why you wouldn't call it with the argument `8` to produce the output you want rather than `17`, and produce full lines at a time rather that two halves.

If, however, the two halves solution is what you really want, and the lenght of the final row is the argument you really want, then you do have a number of options. The one that springs most readily to mind is to produce the half-triangles as lists of strings, rather than printing out the half-lines as you produce them. Then you can run a loop to print out the left halves followed by the right halves on the same line.

It would look something like this:

```
def top_right(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size // 2 + 1
    out = [""]
    line = ""
    for num in range(nsize):
        line = str(num+1) + line
        out.append(line)
    return out

def top_left(size):
    line = ''
    nsize = size // 2
    out = []
    line = ""
    for num in range(nsize):
        line += str(num+1)
        out.append((nsize-len(line))*' ' + line)
    return out

def full_diamond(size):
    tl, tr = top_left(size), top_right(size)
    for left, right in zip(tl, tr):
        print(left+right)

full_diamond(17)
```